# Building a package with generated Python files

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

### Problem statement

When building a Python package I want the build tool to automatically execute the steps to generate the necessary Python files and include them in the package.

Here are some details about the project:

- the project repository contains only the hand-written Python and YAML files
- to have a fully functional package the YAML files must be compiled into Python scripts
- once the Python files are generated from YAMLs, the program needed to compile them is no longer necessary (build dependency).
- the hand-written and generated Python files are then packaged together.

The package would then be uploaded to PyPI.

I want to achieve the following:

- When the user installs the package from PyPI, all necessary files required for the package to function are included and it is not necessary to perform any compile steps
- When the user checks-out the repository and builds the package with `python -m build . --wheel`, the YAML files are automatically compiled into Python and included in the package. Compiler is required.
- When the user checks-out the repository and installs the package from source, the YAML files are automatically compiled into Python and installed. Compiler is required.
- (nice to have) When the user checks-out the repository and installs in editable mode, the YAML files are compiled into Python. The user is free to make modifications to both generated and hand-written Python files. Compiler is required.

I have a repository with the following layout:

```
├── <project>
│   └── <project>
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── hand_written.py
│       └── specs
│           └── file.ksc (YAML file)
└── pyproject.toml
```

And the functional package should look something like this

```
├── <project>
│   └── <project>
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── hand_written.py
│       └── generated
│           └── file.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── <other package metadata>
```

How can I achieve those goals?

### What I have so far

As I am very fresh to Python packaging, I have been struggling to understand the relations between the `pyproject.toml`, `setup.cfg` and `setup.py` and how I can use them to achieve the goals I have outlined above. So far I have a `pyproject.toml` with the following content:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "<package>"
version = "xyz"
description = "<description>"
authors = [ <authors> ]
dependencies = [
    "kaitaistruct",
]
```

From reading the setuptools documentation, I understand that there are the build commands, such as:

- `build_py` -- simply copies Python files into the package (no compiling; works differently in editable mode)
- `build_ext` -- builds C/C++ modules (not relevant here?)

I suppose adding the compile steps for the YAML files will involve writing a `setup.py` file and overwriting a command, but I don't know if this is the right approach, whether it will even work, or if there are better methods, such as using a different build backend.

### Alternative approaches

A possible alternative approach would be to manually compile the YAML files prior to starting the installation or build of the package.

Comment: You most likely need a `setup.py`. Since you also have `pyproject.toml`, you most likely do not need `setup.cfg`. -- Regarding help with the actual custom *setuptools* commands, I can offer this: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/setuptools.html

Comment: @sinoroc Thanks for the comment and providing the resource. It pointed me towards the direction to use the sub-commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I got an answer to my own question.
What I basically needed was setuptools [sub-commands](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/extension.html#supporting-sdists-and-editable-installs-in-build-sub-commands).
Sub-commands allow the build process to be extended with custom steps without having to over-write an existing command.

First, I needed to create `setup.py` file with a class that implements the `Command` protocol.

```
from setuptools import Command

class BuildKsy(Command):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.build_lib = None
        self.editable_mode = False

    def initialize_options(self):
        """Initialize command state to defaults"""
        ...

    def finalize_options(self):
        """
        Populate the command state. This is where I traverse the directory
        tree to search for the *.ksc files to compile them later.
        The self.set_undefined_options is used to inherit the `build_lib`
        attribute from the `build_py` command.
        """
        self.set_undefined_options("build_py", ("build_lib", "build_lib"))
        ...

    def run(self):
        """
        Perform actions with side-effects, such as invoking a ksc to python compiler. 
        The directory to which outputs are written depends on `editable_mode` attribute.
        When editable_mode == False, the outputs are written to directory pointed by build_lib.
        When editable_mode == True, the outputs are written in-place, 
        i.e. into the directory containing the sources.
        The `run` method is not executed during sdist builds.
        """
        ...

    def get_output_mapping(self):
        """
        Return dict mapping output file paths to input file paths
        Example:
            dict = { "build/lib/output.py": "project/specs/file.ksc" }
        """
        ...

    def get_outputs(self):
        """Return list containing paths to output files (generated *.py files in my case)"""
        ...

    def get_source_files(self):
        """Returns list containing paths to input files (*.ksc YAMLs in my case)"""
```

Finally I needed to register the custom build sub-command.

```
import setuptools.command.build
setuptools.command.build.build.sub_commands.append(("build_ksy", None))
```

The `sub_commands.append()` takes a tuple containing the command name and a second parameter that can either be `None` or a method.

The documentation is a bit lacking in this area, but looking at the source code I figured out what the second parameter is. If the second parameter is a method, then it will be executed. The method must return a boolean value. If the method returns `True`, the sub-command will be executed in the build process. If the second parameter is `None`, then the sub-command will also be executed in the build process. Otherwise the sub-command will not be executed. [Here is the piece of code in setuptools that handles it.](https://github.com/pypa/distutils/blob/4435cec31b8eb5712aa8bf993bea3f07051c24d8/distutils/cmd.py#L329)

Lastly, it is necessary to call `setuptools.setup()`. The `cmdclass` parameter must map the command name from the `sub_commands.append` tuple parameter to the Python class implementing the command.

```
setuptools.setup(cmdclass={"build_ksy": BuildKsy})
```

After going through the above steps it is possible to simply use

```
python -m build . --wheel
python -m build . --sdist
```

to build wheels and source distributions respectively. The wheel will contain the fully processed distribution that does not require the user to perform the `ksc` compile step. The source distribution however will still require the user to execute the `ksc` compile step and requires the compiler to be installed.

It is also possible to have an editable installation by calling

```
pip install -e <package-dir>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add to @bluv's answer with my approach using the Command class retrieved from versioneer. Here is my directory structure.

```
 package-root-name
  |
  ├── scripts
        ├── generate_files.sh
  ├── src
  │    ├── modulename
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── path
                 ├── generated
                        ├── files
```

and this is my `setup.py`

```
def update_cmdclass(cmdclass):
    if "build_py" in cmdclass:
        _build_py = cmdclass["build_py"]
    else:
        _build_py = build_py

    class UpdateBindings(_build_py):

        def run(self):
            self: Command = self
            _build_py.run(self)
            self.spawn(["bash", "./scripts/generate_files.sh"])
    cmdclass["build_py"] = UpdateBindings
    return cmdclass



setup_args = dict(
    name='package-root-name',
    version=versioneer.get_version(),
    cmdclass=update_cmdclass(versioneer.get_cmdclass()),
    maintainer='Foo Bar',
    maintainer_email='foo@bar.com',
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    install_requires=install_requires + local_requires,
    package_data={
        "modulename": ["path/generated/file/*.py"],
    }
)
```

The above `setup.py` uses the `update_cmdclass` method to run the `generate_files.sh` script during build. Then use the `package_data` attribute to point to the generated files. The dict key in the `package_data` needs to be the name of a module within `package_dir` (i.e. having a **init**.py). In this case, it's the `src` directory. During build, the newly generated files is included in the build package.